# Ruby on Rails Server Run error: IPAddr::InvalidAddressError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I created new rails app like this.

```
rails new my_app -d postgres
cd my_app
bundle install
rails s
```

Server started successfully like this:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And when I access http://localhost:3000 on my browser, I got following error:

```
IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:560:in `in6_addr'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:497:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:515:in `new'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:515:in `coerce_other'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:171:in `include?'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `block in include?'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `any?'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `include?'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/request.rb:16:in `from_whitelisted_ip?'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whiny_request.rb:8:in `from_whitelisted_ip?'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
    from /Users/ror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I am using rvm and ruby 2.3.1, rails 5.0.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any cloud IDE, like c9 or something else?

Comment: No, I am developing on my local machine.

Comment: check output of "echo $IP" and "echo $PORT"

Comment: echo $IP : " "
echo $PORT : " "

Comment: both of those are space

Comment: Try this: "rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000"

Comment: Are you saving some ip info in any database table?

Comment: @Flip Do u manage to fix this problem?

Comment: @Flip ?????????